# How to get 3 highest value from table and print them out?

Tags: php, mysql, row

I have a table called pvpstats. It has 4 columns; id, name, kills and deaths. I have to get 3 highest values from "kills" and sort them from highest to lowest and include also the name. Like 3-top statistics! And because I'm new with MySQL I need an step-by-step quide...

This is how my .php looks at the moment:

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$dbuser = "usernm";
$dbpass = "passwd";
$dbname = "pvpstats";

mysql_connect($server, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT kills FROM pvpstats ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 3");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo print_r($row,true);

?>
```

Connection is working and it is showing the highest value but without name. And only the highest when it should show 3 highest

Comment: What's working? Not working? What specific questions do you have?

Comment: Connection is working and it is showing the highest value but without name. And only the highest when it should show 3 highest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` will only echo 1 row

user while loop to echo all data.

Answer (score 1):

Well for one, you should use:

```
print_r($row);
```

not:

```
echo print_r($row,true);
```

*print_r* will automatically output it if you omit the **true** variable, as passing the response to *echo* is just redundant.

Also, since your query will return three rows, you have to loop through it:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
    // or if you just want to output the number, use:
    // echo $row["kills"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it seems,your query syntax does not have any problem. use below codes to find problems.

```
mysql_connect($server, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
```

...

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysql_error());
```